# Show a dialog box fullscreen even after a EditText is focused

Tags: android, android-studio, dialog, android-fullscreen

I have a dialog box which I want to be shown full screen. I've been able to do so putting some effort. But the problem is that, my dialog box contains some EditText view and when an EditText view is getting focused the dialog size is being reduced. I make it full screen as following way:

```
contactInfoDialog = new Dialog(context);
contactInfoDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_contact_info);
contactInfoDialog.show();
Window window = contactInfoDialog.getWindow();
assert window != null;
window.setLayout(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

I understand that when the keyboard is showing the window size is being reduced, so does the dialog box. But I can not find a way to keep it full-screen size. Can anyone please help me?

I built the dialog box as follow:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contact_info_dialog_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contact_info_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/contact_info_back_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/back_button"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="@string/contact_info"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/contact_info_header"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="32dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/contact_info_name_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/contact_info_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/full_name" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/contact_info_email_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/contact_info_name_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/contact_info_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email_address" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/contact_info_phone_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/contact_info_email_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/contact_info_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/mobile_number" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/contact_info_update_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:paddingStart="32dp"
            android:paddingEnd="32dp"
            android:text="@string/update"
            android:textAllCaps="false" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Image of the dialog box before the EditText is in focus.

[image]

Image of the dialog box after the EditText is in focus.

[image]

Comment: Please share activity entry in manifest file.

Comment: `
<activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activities.HomeActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.BookProfile" />
 `
The dialog is being showed in a fragment from the HomeActivity